# Lag in R Time Series is not visible

Tags: r, time-series, lag

I have a time series and a lagged version of the same. But when I plot them side by side, they look identical. Where did the lag go ?

```
set.seed(1)
x = rnorm(100)
y = lag(x, 10)
df = data.frame(x, y)
plot (ts(df)) # they look exactly the same, no time shift
```

Printing the two series on the console also confirms this behavior. I know R internally just maintains an offset for the lag. But I want that to come out in the plot. They should LOOK shifted.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your `x` into a `ts` object first:

```
> foo <- ts(x[1:24],frequency=12)
> foo
          Jan         Feb         Mar         Apr         May         Jun
1 -0.62645381  0.18364332 -0.83562861  1.59528080  0.32950777 -0.82046838
2 -0.62124058 -2.21469989  1.12493092 -0.04493361 -0.01619026  0.94383621
          Jul         Aug         Sep         Oct         Nov         Dec
1  0.48742905  0.73832471  0.57578135 -0.30538839  1.51178117  0.38984324
2  0.82122120  0.59390132  0.91897737  0.78213630  0.07456498 -1.98935170
> lag(foo,12)
          Jan         Feb         Mar         Apr         May         Jun
0 -0.62645381  0.18364332 -0.83562861  1.59528080  0.32950777 -0.82046838
1 -0.62124058 -2.21469989  1.12493092 -0.04493361 -0.01619026  0.94383621
          Jul         Aug         Sep         Oct         Nov         Dec
0  0.48742905  0.73832471  0.57578135 -0.30538839  1.51178117  0.38984324
1  0.82122120  0.59390132  0.91897737  0.78213630  0.07456498 -1.98935170
```

You see that `lag(foo,12)` is shifted by twelve months. Let's plot:

```
> par(mfrow=c(2,1))
> plot(foo)
> plot(lag(foo,12))
```

[image: lag]

`foo` and its lagged series still look the same - but you now see that the horizontal axis has shifted by 1, which is the lag (identical to the `frequency`).

Comment: Actually you don't need to set `frequency` and you can see it better when plotted one over another. something like `set.seed(1);
x = ts(rnorm(100));
y = lag(x, k=10);
plot(x, col = "red");
lines(y, col = "blue")`